# Creating a drawn audio reactive visual

Tags: audio, processing

I'm looking to create this project in processing, however, I'm finding the terminology a bit hard. I'm not sure how to call the effect where the line is staying permanently throughout the song to 'draw' the music data.

I would appreciate any guidance on what tutorials I could look at or an answer from someone.

My aim is to create something as close to this as possible:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bb5PTitqtlc&t=58s

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. But I'll try to help in a general sense:

You need to [break your problem down into smaller pieces](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and then take those pieces on one at a time. Write down exactly what you want to happen, in English, and that will be an algorithm that you can think about implementing with code.

Get something simple working. Can you write a simple sketch that plays a song? Then work your way forward in small steps. Can you write a simple sketch that prints out some numeric values based on the song that's playing? Separately from that, can you create a very simple visualization using hard-coded numbers? Get all of that working separately before you think about combining them into a sketch that shows a visualization based on a song that's playing.

Then if you get stuck, you can post a more specific question along with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks kevin, that helps me understand a little more how the community works! Kind Regards,